# Importing .tex table to lyx using tex2lyx

Tags: tex, lyx

I'm writing a document in lyx and I have tables that are .tex files. I usually import them via the menu, but I would like to import them directly using a snippet of tex code in the lyx file using directly tex2lyx in the document.

How do I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Insert > File > Child Document and select your .tex file. You can have it show a preview if you want. For more questions, please ask on tex.stackexchange.com